# Kafka error: could not find or load main class kafka.admin.topiccommand

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm on Windows 7 and downloaded and unzipped the files into my chosen directory but getting the following error when trying to run a describe command:

```
could not find or load main class kafka.admin.Topiccommand
```

command trying to run:

```
kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper SERVER_NAME --topic TOPIC_NAME
```

My teammates say they only downloaded and unzippped and it works for them. Am I missing something? I am running these commands from the bin/windows directory.

Comment: Have you started Zookeeper?

Comment: When I run the start command for zookeeper I get a similar message: `Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain`

Comment: Can you share the exact error trace when trying to start zookeeper?

Comment: That's all I get in the command line when running the command

Comment: I actually downloaded another version  and now getting this when trying to start zookeeper: `C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\config\zookeeper.properties
Error: Could not find or load main class ;C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\libs\aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b32.jar;C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.
0\libs\argparse4j-0.7.0.jar;C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\libs\commons-lang3-3.5.jar;C:\Users\FILEPATH\kafka_2.11-1.0.0\libs\connect-api-1.0.0.jar;

Comment: At least that's part of if. The whole thing is really long

Answer (score -1):

So it seems there was an issue with my CLASSPATH so I unset it by running `set CLASSPATH=` and I was able to start zookeeper and then run other Kafka commands.